# which curve tool would be the most suitable to reproduce this profile on the top

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves

I found this cool structure and I would somehow like to create a similar one in blender.

1. Which curve tool would be the best to replicate the profile? The idea would be to create the profile and extrude it in Z and pinch it (S key) near the bottom to make it vase like.
2. It would be also really cool if it is possible to make it parametrically so that the profile can be varied.
   Any tips would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: maybe try this pretty cool tool: [diferential growth](https://ibb.co/xDdpgpQ), got something [quite 'similar'](https://ibb.co/xDdpgpQ) after a few tries -you can extract the profile if you want, but shapes are great-

Comment: That looks promising… is that an add-on available by default in blender?

Comment: sorry [here's the link](https://boris.okunskiy.name/posts/blender-differential-growth)

Comment: Thanks! Will explore it!

Comment: it's fun, even if you won't get that exact shape... try to understand settings, then use modifiers on surface, LaplacianSmooth is a good one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a curve bevel and curve taper to keep it parametric

1. Start with a vertical bezier curve
2. Use a (modified) bezier circle to use as Bevel Object
3. Add another bezier curve as Taper Object (orientation and origin point *is important*)

(then solidify/subdivide/bevel/etc)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess this could be used with the differential growth tool

Comment: I was looking for a way to add a slight rotation on the vertical axis. I didnt get it working with the screw modifier...

Comment: Hi :). Simple deform modifier/twist works perfectly